# Find XPath for element with dynamic location on page (jump straight to element?)

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

I am trying to write Selenium tests for a webpage reloading alerts every so often as the database changes frequently. The alerts are in a `<ul>` as an `<li>`, and all have unique titles as an `<h4>` element below the `<li>` (with a lot of divs above this).

It'll look something like:

```
<h4 title="Title" class="message-title alarm-list-name ng-binding">Displayed Value matches Title Value</h4>
```

When I use Chrome's "Copy XPath" functionality, I get paths like `//*[@id=": 0"]/a/div[2]/h5[1]`, but of course this changes every time the page reloads (and I still am getting "no element found" when I use this one). I want to know if there's a way to jump straight to the `<h4>` with its particular value, as this would be the easiest way to handle this problem, I think. I've tried `//h4[@title="Title"]`, but I get no element found.

I've also tried `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Text"));` with similar results. I tend to think xpath will be better because it seems more versatile.

If you have other Selenium recommendations, I'd appreciate it if you could demonstrate using them with the webdriver plugin for Jmeter in javascript, since that's the tool I've been using.

Comment: `//h4[@title="Title"]` will go straight to that element with that attribute. Are you able to provide more of the HTML surrounding this element?

Comment: When using Chrome Developer Tools to inspect the Element  is the XPath //h4[@title="Title"] pointing to the element you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of more information would have helped us to address your query whether you want to extract the text **Displayed Value matches Title Value** or you want to want to invoke any method on it.

However as per the *HTML* you have shared as the *WebElement* is a *Angular Element* so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* with proper *ExpectedConditions* as follows (*Java Solution*):

- To extract the text **Displayed Value matches Title Value** :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("//h4[@class='message-title alarm-list-name ng-binding' and @title='Title']"), "Displayed Value matches Title Value"));
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h4[@class='message-title alarm-list-name ng-binding' and @title='Title']")).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```

Comment: I am trying to invoke methods on it. Will try this when I get some time today.